# How to slow the scrolling speed of background image

Tags: css, html, parallax, vertical-scrolling

I wanted to make a parallax effect but I try lots of ways still can't do it

```
.top
{
background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.8),rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url('../image/Kinkis-Bottomless-Brunch-Lead-Image.jpg');
height: 100vh;
background-size: cover;
background-position:center;
background-attachment:fixed;
}


<div class="top">
    <div class="main">

        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Limited Edition</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="account">Account</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

now I have half of the parallax effect which is the background image are fixed, without moving and the next image will cover the previous image, but now I want it to become when I scrolling down the background image will move down too but just slower than the original speed.

Comment: please share a fiddle to help you

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6gcax9vq/1/     this is my coding on fiddle

Comment: your fiddle is not clear. pls check out this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp